# PostgresQL PG Barman backup setup

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to setup postgres with pgbarman. While checking barman check  i am geetting WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)

Could some one please help me with it

Comment: Take a look at the PostgreSQL log files to check for errors from your `archive_command`. Most likely you have not configured ssh correctly, per the instructions in the documentation.

Comment: I have configured postgres and barman currectly. This is working fine with postgres master. When i try to take backup too from  postgres , i am  getting following error.

Comment: 2016-06-10 06:20:03,592 [5693] barman.server ERROR: Check 'WAL archive' failed for server 'smapgrep02.example.com'
2016-06-10 06:20:03,783 [5693] barman.server ERROR: Check 'backup maximum age' failed for server 'smapgrep02.example.com'
2016-06-10 06:20:03,928 [5693] barman.server ERROR: Check 'not in recovery' failed for server 'smapgrep02.example.com'

Comment: No, the *PostgreSQL* logs, not the barman logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved changing the archive postgresql.conf

Before:

```
archive_mode = on
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@ipbarman:INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY/%f'
```

After:

```
archive_mode = on
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@ipbarman:/data/barman/pgsql-master/incoming/%f'
```

**restart postgres for apply changes.

I found directory with this command(INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY):

```
$ barman show-server pgsql-master
```

Next step, i use:

```
barman switch-xlog --force --archive pgsql-master
```

Try check again.